# How can we fetch >100 comments using YouTube API v2?

Tags: youtube-api

I know that YouTube API v2 has been deprecated, however, v3 has no provision to fetch comments from youtube videos. So, I have no choice but to use v2 to fetch the comments.

I read online that we are allowed to fetch up to 1000 comments from a youtube video, but I can only fetch 50 results at a time. So, I used the following urls to fetch the data:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JsDY1Ha83M8/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JsDY1Ha83M8/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=51
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JsDY1Ha83M8/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=101
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JsDY1Ha83M8/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=151
....
```

and so on, till start-index=1001

The thing is, youtube stops returning comments from start-index=101 and onwards. So, I can only fetch 100 comments. I need to be able to fetch 1000 comments. How can I do that?

To reproduce the issue I am facing, simply go to:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JsDY1Ha83M8/comments?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=101

and you'll see that there are no "entry" fields.

Comment: API V2 is deprecated, use API V3

Comment: V3 doesn't allow comment extraction yet.

Answer (score 1):

As it was announced in Vidcon this year, v3 comments are in testing stage. For interested parties, we include them in testing process, as well as production version is so soon to be launched.